# How to disable/hide/remove fields inside the kendo UI pop up editable for HTTP POST

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular-kendo

I have this code for my schema:

```
schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        col1: {
                            type: "string", editable: true, nullable: false,
                            validation:{ required: { message: "Name is Required." } }
                        },
                        col2: {
                            type: "string", editable: true, nullable: false,
                            validation:{ required: { message: "Please Select a Main Language." } }
                        },
                        col3:{
                            type: "Array[]", editable: true, nullable: false,
                            validation:{ required: { message: "Please Select Supported Language(s)." } }
                        },
                        col4: {
                            type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true
                        },
                        col5: {
                            type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Columns code snippet

```
{
                    field: "col4",
                    title: "Column4",
                    width:"200px",
                    editable:false,
                    nullable: true
                },
                {
                    field: "col5",
                    title: "Column5",
                    width:"200px",
                    editable:false,
                    nullable: true
                }
```

I would like to disable the last two (status and unlocalized count). As you can see I have already used the editable and nullable. My goal is to send an HTTP post without the two which has this JSON format

```
{"col1":"string", "col2":"string","col3":["string"]}
```

Comment: Found out the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
I used a editor that has a function.

```
function(container){

  $('label[for=status]').parent().remove();

}
```

which looks like this now

```
{
  field: "status",
  title: "Status",
  editable:false,
  editor:function(container){
                       $('label[for=status]').parent().remove();
                   }
}
```

Comment: So, if my first column is Guid and I want to hide from end user, it will still be loaded into my view model and read.    Can you show all your code in this View?

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo way to do it would be to add field called **Edit** in the kendoGridSource like so:

```
edit: function (e) {
           e.container.find('[for="none"]').parent().remove();
           e.container.find('[data-container-for="none"]').remove();
 },
```

In there you would look for the fields the that have `for="none"` and remove all of them, same would go for the container.

Then in your schema, The field you want to edit out:

```
{
  field: "none",
  title: "Column5",
  width:"200px",
},
```